# How can I make the eventListener work in a table if there is an image inside it?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple table, and my task is to put an image in the table cells when clicking, or to remove them if there is already an image inside. My code is the following:

```
const table = document.querySelector("tbody")
table.addEventListener("click", clickTile)

function clickTile(e){
    if(e.target.matches("td")){
        const row = e.target.closest("tr").rowIndex
        const col = e.target.closest("td").cellIndex
        placeImage(row, col)
    }
}

function placeImage(row, col){
    const cell = table.rows[row].cells[col]
    if(cell.innerHTML != ""){
        cell.innerHTML= ""
        return
    }
    
    cell.innerHTML = "<img src=\"image.png\" height=\"20px\" width=\"20px\"/>"
}
```

It doesn't work if I click directly on the image, only if I click somewhere where I'm still inside the cell, but not on the image.

Comment: I bet `e.target.matches("td")` only matches the td, not its children, so you'd probably need to add to that if-statement to include the td's children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) as well in the `if` statement to capture the `td` element and all of its descendents.

Then query for the image in the cell, remove if it is there, or add it if it isn't.

```
function clickTile(e) {
  const td = e.target.closest("td");

  if (target.closest("td")) {
    const row = e.target.closest("tr").rowIndex;
    const col = td.cellIndex;
    const image = td.querySelector('img');

    if (image === null) {
      placeImage(row, col);
    } else {
      removeImage(image);
    }
  }
}

function removeImage(image) {
  image.remove();
}

function placeImage(row, col){
  const cell = table.rows[row].cells[col]
  cell.innerHTML = "<img src=\"image.png\" height=\"20px\" width=\"20px\"/>"
}
```